# C# interchangeable properties

Tags: c#, types, properties, weakly-typed

I'm trying to create a substitute for kind of property, that accepts multiple types as inputs/outputs.

Here is some pseudo code of one ugly solution:

http://pastebin.com/gbh4SrZX

Basically i have piece of data and i need to be able assign multiple types to it, and react accordingly. I have pieces of data that i operate with, and i need efficient way to manage loading them from file names when needed, while maintaining the same code, if I'm manipulating with data, that's already loaded.

This would be awesome:

```
SomeDataClass data1 = new SomeDataClass();
SomeDataClass data2 = new SomeDataClass();

data1.Data = "somefile.dat";
data2.Data = data1.Data;
```

while SomeDataClass.Data is not type of string.

Comment: You picked the wrong language

Comment: @Luis how so? that does not necessarily follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do much of that with an implicit conversion operator, i.e.

```
class SomeDataClass {
    public SomeData Data {get;set;}
}
class SomeData {
    static SomeData Load(string path) {
        return new SomeData(); // TODO
    }
    public static implicit operator SomeData(string path)
    {
        return Load(path);
    }
}
static class Program {
    static void Main()
    {
        SomeDataClass data1 = new SomeDataClass();
        SomeDataClass data2 = new SomeDataClass();

        data1.Data = "somefile.dat"; // this is a load
        data2.Data = data1.Data; // this is not a load
    }
}
```

However! Frankly, I would consider it more desirable to just make the operation explicit:

```
class SomeDataClass {
    public SomeData Data {get;set;}
}
class SomeData {
    public static SomeData Load(string path) {
        return new SomeData(); // TODO
    }
}
static class Program {
    static void Main()
    {
        SomeDataClass data1 = new SomeDataClass();
        SomeDataClass data2 = new SomeDataClass();

        data1.Data = SomeData.Load("somefile.dat");
        data2.Data = data1.Data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `dynamic`?

```
class A {
    public dynamic property1 { get; set; }
    public dynamic property2 { get; set; }
}

class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        A a = new A();
        A b = new A();

        a.property1 = "hello world!";
        b.property2 = a.property1;

        Console.WriteLine(b.property2); // writes "hello world!"
    }
}
```

Comment: I *think* this misses the thrust of the question, which is that it wants different handling of different object types. Frankly, `dynamic` here adds nothing that isn't done by `object`.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. However, with my understanding of the question (wanting to assign any value to a property), dynamic will allow for accessing a types methods, properties, etc.. whereas object would need explicit casting to provide this functionality. If I misunderstood the question, I apologise.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem you're trying to solve with this really is, but it seems to me like you'd be better of with using  a byte[], working with a stream of data, loaded either from disk or somewhere else.

Also consider just coding to a common Interface, instead of using dynamic and object.